# Framework auto-scale container docker on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, autoscaling

Is there any framework that creates auto-scale container docker on AWS?

For example: I have a Wordpress application, and based on HTTP requests, automatically create a new instance of docker. Is possible? How?

I do not want to use auto-scale policy based threshold (cpu, and ram usage ...)

Already researched the Kubernetes, Mesos and Deis and found that these frameworks do not automatically scale. I need to manually run a command to create a new docker resource.

Comment: It sounds like you want something to magically handle scaling for you, but you are rejecting Amazon's tools that magically handle scaling for you.

Comment: Amazon has not auto-scale container docker. Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (EC2) has auto-scale, but Amazon Container Service (ECS) does not auto-scale. I need to auto-scale in container docker on AWS.

Comment: AWS ECS now supports auto scaling of docker containers.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/scaling-amazon-ecs-services-automatically-using-amazon-cloudwatch-and-aws-lambda/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want PCU or memory, what do you want?  It's trivial in kubernetes to write a helper app that monitors WHATEVER signal and manipulates replication controllers on the fly.  It's much much harder to generically define how to monitor an arbitrary signal.